# Are the subscription products offered by an app on Google Play visible publicly anywhere?

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Quick sanity check here.

Suppose an app in Google Play offers a number of different subscription products. Some are the standard retail products, some are for special events, some are "winback" SKUs, and so on. In other words, not all should be visible to all users or at all times.

My understanding is that the list of subscription SKUs associated with an app in the Google Play Console is completely private. However, I also can't find any documentation that explicitly guarantees this.

Thus the sanity check:

- Is it possible to see a partial or full list of subscription products offered by an app at any public location (including Google Play)?
- If it is not, does that also mean it is not possible to switch from one subscription SKU to another within a workflow presented by Google Play (as opposed to within the app)? I ask this because iOS offers such a feature, but it means you have to be careful about which products you group together.

Thank you!